# how to get a variable to represent a function name for "symbol-function()"

Tags: emacs

I am learning how to program in emacs lisp. I thought I would write a simple function that prints a function definition to the messages buffer. This works fine:

```
(let (
(fDefAsString (symbol-function 'scroll-down)) 
)
(message "%s" fDefAsString)
(switch-to-buffer-other-frame "*Messages*"))
```

but I wanted this to be a function that could take an argument, the argument being the name of the function whose definition I want to see. So I tried this:

```
(defun message-function-definition (nameOfFunction)
(let (
(fDefAsString (symbol-function 'nameOfFunction)) 
)
(message "%s" fDefAsString)
(switch-to-buffer-other-frame "*Messages*")))
```

and then I wrote this:

```
(message-function-definition 'scroll-down)
```

Then I ran "eval-buffer".

I keep getting this error:

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function nameOfFunction)
  symbol-function(nameOfFunction)
  (let ((fDefAsString ...)) (message "%s" fDefAsString) (switch-to-buffer-other-frame "*Messages*"))
  message-function-definition(scroll-down)
  eval((message-function-definition (quote scroll-down)))
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  recursive-edit()
  byte-code("\306   @\307=\203!

I've tried quoting, unquoting, and I've tried to use "nameOfFunction" but I can not get this to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try unquoting?  This works for me:

```
(defun message-function-definition (nameOfFunction)
  (let ((fDefAsString (symbol-function nameOfFunction)))
    (message "%s" fDefAsString)
    (switch-to-buffer-other-frame "*Messages*")))
```

Some hints:

1. Your code is not indented correctly.  If you select the region and re-indent with <kbd>tab</kbd>, it'll be easier to read.
2. You should spend a couple of hours working through the "Emacs Lisp Intro",
   you will have a much better idea of how things work in Emacs-lisp, rather
   than figuring it all by asking one question at a time on StackOverflow.
3. `symbol-function` is not designed to show a human readable definition of
   the function.  In most cases you won't really see anything useful.

   Try this:

   ```
   (find-function-other-window 'scroll-down)
   ```

Comment: if I put (find-function-other-window 'scroll-down) in an empty buffer and run eval-buffer I get : "Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size")"

Comment: I don't.  I'm using Emacs 24.1.  Start emacs with `emacs -Q`.  `scroll-down` isn't a good example because it's defined in C.  But I still see the source fine.

Comment: Now I get "The C source file window.c is not available"

Comment: Strangely, in a blank new buffer, I do this:  (symbol-function 'scroll-down)
and then C-x C-e and all I get is: #<subr scroll-down>
I am not sure what has gone wrong.

Comment: Do you actually want to see the function definition or something else?  You need to have the C sources installed if you do.